# Java Swing Using Multiple packages/classes

Tags: java, swing

Some time ago I wrote a code in a single main class which worked fine. Later I added **JPanel** and **JFrame** in again its single main it again worked fine.

Now I am trying to break the code down and move them into packages.

here is my main
-( src/start/Main.java)-

```
package start;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import frames.*;
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) { 
        MainFrame.createFrame();
        LogoPanel.createLogoPanel();       //this line is the problem
    }
}
```

here is MainFrame 
-(src/frames/MainFrame.java)-

```
package frames;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class MainFrame {

    public static JFrame createFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("App");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(140,140, 1000, 580);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        return frame;
    }

}
```

here is LogoPanel
-(src/frames/LogoPanel.java)-

```
package frames;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LogoPanel {

    public static JPanel createLogoPanel(JFrame frame) {
        JPanel logoPanel = new JPanel ();
        logoPanel.setVisible(true);
        logoPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 80);
        logoPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        logoPanel.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(logoPanel);
        return logoPanel;
    }

}
```

as I said LogoPanel.createLogoPanel(); is the problem . It does not accept createLogoPanel(JFrame frame) from me ? setting it to null doesn't show the panel at all . anyway I can make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `createLogoPanel` takes a `JFrame` type argument.

But I don't see you passing an argument when you are actually invoking the method.

Do something along the lines of :

```
    JFrame frame = MainFrame.createFrame();
    LogoPanel.createLogoPanel(frame);
```

This error seem to suggest a lack of understanding about basic Java syntax and concepts. If you are able to accumulate knowledge in this area it will benefit you greatly in the future.

Comment: It's called a method argument, or a parameter. Again, I hope you take my advice into consideration.